# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR)

Tags: apache, apache2

I have unique apache http server which deliver html/css/js ressources for all clients.

each client access to his private account with subdomain
client-1.myurl.com
client-2.myurl.com

And I use [mod_macro](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_macro.html) with ProxyPass to map request of a subdomain url to an external ip server:
by example

https://pastebin.com/Xp8ydjZD

But sometimes i got `net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` in my console while navigating on my website and a lot 503 errors, here is my apache log error file : https://pastebin.com/PjU7D3Py

Various error in apache log :

1. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ...
2. AH01102: error reading status line from remote server at.myurl.com:8082, referer: https://at.myurl....
3. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.  : AH00957: HTTPS: attempt to connect to zzz.zz.zzz.zz:8082 (ij.myurl.com) failed....
4. AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: ij.myurl.com, referer:...

Screenshot
[image]